# Android Studio Emulator isn't coming up

Tags: android, mobile

Is just staying on this screen

[image]

This is on my mac and I've updated everything I can see, including Android studio and HAXM.
I've tried different android devices like a nexus 6P and a nexus 5 but same issue.

I do seem to haxm running ok based on:

[image]

What else might be causing the emulator to not come up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I didn't have the 64 bit version.  I delete the image and downloaded a new one using x86_64 and this one worked normally and brought up the home screen in the usual 10-15 seconds from power on.

[image]